# How do I extend UserCreationForm to include email field

Tags: python, django

I managed to get the stock standard User Creation Form to work. Which included just the username, password1 and password2 field. However, when I try to include the email field it never shows up in my template. I think I'm missing something in my view perhaps. Here is my code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm 

def register_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = UserCreationForm()

return render_to_response('stories/register.html', args)
```

**register.html**

```
<form action = "/register/" method = "POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 

    <p>
    {{ form.username.label_tag }}
    {{ form.username}}
    </p>

    <p> 
    {{ form.email.label_tag }}
    {{ form.email }}
    </p>

    <p>
    {{ form.password1.label_tag }}
    {{ form.password1 }}
    </p>

    <p>
    {{ form.password2.label_tag }}
    {{ form.password2 }}
    </p>

    <input type = "submit" value = "register" />
</form>
```

All of the fields in this file are being rendered into the view, **Except** the email field.

Can anyone spot why?!

Comment: How do you import `UserCreationForm` in views.py? I bet you are importing the wrong `UserCreationForm`. Also give your form subclass different name like `UserCreationWithEmailForm` or `UserCreateForm`.

Comment: @ozgur I just have "from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm" near the top of the views.py page. Is that right?

Comment: Can you update your question and show us how you are importing it in views.py?

Comment: You import the original form class in your views.py instead of your custom one from your forms.py

Comment: I realised what you meant. I resolved the issue for now. It was meant to be imported like this : 'from stories.forms import UserCreationForm'. Thanks @ozgur

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `UserCreationForm` in views.py. You should import your own form not the Django's one:

**stories/views.py**

```
from stories.forms import UserCreationForm
...
```

Besides that, you don't have to wrap all your fields with `<p></p>` individually as there exists [`form.as_p()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) for this job.

**register.html**

```
<form action = "/register/" method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason I wrapped all the fields with <p> tags was because the formatting came out all weird! It was the only fix I could come up with D:

Comment: I don't think it is something you can't handle with using css :)

Comment: Overall the updates to the Question and this Answer worked great for me. I had some conditional logic in my base template {% is user.is_anonymous%} that had links using {% url 'viewname'} that broke, but since I didn't need them, I just overode that block (my nav bar) and then it all worked fine. 

thanks for the good code!

Comment: If you care about nice HTML sources look at [_Class_ BoundField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField) in django documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm new with django and I tried what you posted and I had to changed to work ... Here's what I did.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

**signup.html**

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<body class="body_login">
  <form method="post" class="form-signup">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form  %}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-dark">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email",)
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from accounts.forms import SignupForm

class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'stories/register.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In forms.py change the name of class UserCreationForm from to something else:

UserCreationForm -> ProfileCreation Form

`class ProfileCreation(UserCreationForm)`

2. in views.py import this class:

`from . forms import ProfileCreation`

You have imported the UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth.forms in your view. So the forms.py has been skipped.