# Using a registration form to add to custom user fields (django)

Tags: django, model, field, registration

I'm creating custom user models for a registration form in django, but I'm having some problems getting the data into the database. Currently the users can register and their username, password, email, first name and last name are saved, but all the other form data isn't saving into the object. Below are my forms and the output:

Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    medication = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    medical_history = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    DOB = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateAccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("username","password","password2","first_name","last_name",
                  "gender","medication","medical_history","DOB","email","telephone",
                  "address","city","state","postcode")
```

views.py:

```
def create_account(request):
    form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
        medication = form.cleaned_data['medication']
        medical_history = form.cleaned_data['medical_history']
        DOB = form.cleaned_data['DOB']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        telephone = form.cleaned_data['telephone']
        address = form.cleaned_data['address']
        city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        postcode = form.cleaned_data['postcode']
        if password == password2:
            if (password_verification(password)) == 3:
                if (username_verification(username)) == False:
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_account')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_account')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_account')
    return render(request, "create_account.html", {'form': form})
```

In the django admin window, the user is registering to the database with the create_user fields, but none of the added custom fields are saving in the available columns. Any help would be great this is really bugging me. Below is a pic of the empty fields, cheers! [image]

Answer (score 3):

You are saving User only `user.save()` so other `Profile` ( please change your `user` table to something meaningful `Profile`.

And also you don't need `password` `first_name` `last_name` `email` in your profile as well.

And I'll suggest to use the `ModelForm` to save the Profile table.

```
user_form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)    

if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():  
    # save the form after your password check
    user_form.save()
    profile_form.save()
```

Comment: I've changed the model name to Profile, thankyou for the suggestion. Would form.save() go in the views file?

Comment: So in models.py I dont need password, email etc. what about a username field? Also in forms.py in the ModelForm fields, would i still include username, password, email. etc?

Comment: please you have to check Django Users... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: By default Django user model has those fields you don't need that in `profile` table,. right ?

Comment: I have updated my post with the edited views, models, forms. Is it looking accurate?

Comment: yeah your `profile` model is okay but you have to create two form. One is for profile and another one is for Django User

Comment: check this answer they use UserCreationForm  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860296/how-do-i-extend-usercreationform-to-include-email-field