# authenticate creates the user but without email

Tags: python, django

when I use `user = authenticate(username=username, email=email, password=password)` the user is created but without the email.

I have a old project where this code worked perfectly but now it doesn't work in  any project.

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as django_login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, email=email, password=password)
            django_login(request, user)
            return redirect('profile/')

    form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}
<main>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password1">
    <p>Repeat password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password2">
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
  </form>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
```

Email isn't included in the UserCreatedForm. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm)

Comment: Explaining your code and how it solves the problem will raise the quality of your answer, and help learning users.

Comment: The probles is that email return None

Answer (score 0):

So, like Mint said the `UserCreationForm` doesn't include email. Why does that matter? No errors get thrown or anything.

`UserCreationForm.save()` isn't saving the `email` field because it doesn't know about it. What you'll need to do is subclass `UserCreationForm` to include the email field, then include that field in the overridden `save()` call as well. Here's how you might go about that:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Credit to this question which I took the OP's form subclass from: [How do I extend UserCreationForm to include email field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860296/how-do-i-extend-usercreationform-to-include-email-field)