# Django issue with validating data in form

Tags: python, django

So I've been working my way through this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/#register-new-users), and I've run into a problem I can't figure out. I'm hoping someone can show me the way. I have a new user registration form I'm working on, and I can't get the data to validate with `form.is_valid()`. In views.py, the `if form.is_valid()` is supposed to validate the data inputted into the form, but instead it returns "Invalid" no matter what. I'm relatively new to Python and Django, so any assistance would be appreciated.

views.py:

```
# main/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from main.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html', {})

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')

def admin(request):
    return render(request, 'admin')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(
            request, 'users/register.html',
            {'form': CustomUserCreationForm}
        )
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Validated!</h1>')
#            return render(redirect(reverse('dashboard')))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Invalid</h1>')
```

forms.py:

```
# main/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('email',)
```

register.html:

```
<!-- main/templates/users/register.html -->

{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}
<h2>Register</h2>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Back to login</a>
{% endblock %}
```

the main urls.py:

```
# homesite/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from main import views
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from main.views import dashboard, register


app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dashboard/', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
]
```

The error message:

```
ValueError at /register/

The view main.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    https://example.com/register/
Django Version:     4.2.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

The view main.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Exception Location:     /home/lennys/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 332, in check_response
Raised during:  main.views.register
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.10.6
Python Path:    

['/home/lennys/dev/example.com',
 '/home/lennys/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 16 Jun 2023 08:58:17 -0700
```

The traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://example.com/register/

Django Version: 4.2.1
Python Version: 3.10.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lennys/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lennys/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "/home/lennys/dev/example.com/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 332, in check_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: The view main.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2):

It was not validating your password `{'password_mismatch': 'The two password fields didn’t match.'}` due to the form on how you are [extending your form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860296/how-do-i-extend-usercreationform-to-include-email-field), so just replace with the code below:

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using Niko's code and tweaking a few other things. Django was actually working, I was inputting bad data. Django would throw the "The view main.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" error when I tried to register an **existing** user, one that was already added. So I kept using "testuser" as the username, not realizing that it was working as expected. You have to input a unique username each time, or Django returns "None", meaning the account was already registered.

I also had to tweak my view a bit. Here's the working "register" function:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(
            request, 'users/register.html',
            {'form': CustomUserCreationForm}
        )
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html') 
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Invalid</h1>')
```

This, plus adding Niko's code into forms.py, was all I needed:

forms.py:

```
# main/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.save()
        return user
```

Note that I had to add `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` at the top too.